# How to lookup a row to calculate a simple average?

Tags: excel, average

Here is my spreadsheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tO92.jpg

I need to calculate the **average** of a range of cells. This is for cell E5.

The beginning of the range is given by `week start`:
So the start of the range is cell B2 (because it's the only row with `week start` as it's `date`).

The end of the range is simply the `weight` of row 4.

**In this particular case output would be identical as: `AVERAGE(B2:B4)`**

Instead of saying directly `B2`, I want to say: 'The `weight` in the row that starts with `week start`'

I should then be able to auto fill this formula to the rest of the spreadsheet.

In this sense, `week start` is a kind of key that tells me where the average starts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `AVERAGEIFS()`?

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&J5,A:A,"<"&A5)
```

Comment: Fixed it. I just assumed he wanted the `Week Start` and `Week End` of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Use this In E5 then copy/drag down.:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(J5,A:A,0)):B4)
```

Comment: What a talent :D

Comment: To the sniper, who down voted and did not leave an explanation, scared of little ol' me?  What could possibly warrant the down vote?  This formula does exactly what the OP asked.

Comment: Not only it does, but it teaches an interesting theme; using `INDEX` as an endpoint of a range.